# What does a table with only 2 foreign keys do?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, erd

I've researched about MySQL and I've come across this interesting ERD. I understand all of it except the `user_chat` table here. It has 2 foreign keys referencing from table `chat` and `user`. What does that do anyway? Does that mean:

1. I have to `INSERT INTO message, chat, user_chat` on manual when there is a new chat?
2. I can only do `SELECT` statement with this `user_chat` table?
3. The `user_chat` cannot contain other columns like `favorite` in case people want to quickly access it?
4. Can I delete a row in `user_chat` table, since they are not `unique`?

I'm self-learning and still a beginner on this subject so it would mean a lot if this can be explained to help me understand it. Much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a many-to-many relationship between `user` and `chat`, that is to say that one user can participate in multiple chats, and each chat can have multiple users participating.

This sort of relationship is impossible to represent directly using `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, which can only enforce a one-to-many relationship. To work around this, database designers use an "intersection entity" table like `user_chat`, which allows the many-to-many relationship to be reduced to a "one-to-many-to-one" relationship.

When you create a new chat you insert a record into `user_chat` for each participant, and for any new participants that join the chat in progress. The main use of this intersection in this example is to allow you to easily search for all participants in a chat (in order to notify them of new messages, for example), or to find all conversations in which a specific user has participated.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. In the `user_chat` table, should I add a `UNIQUE` constrain on the 2 foreign keys to avoid duplicate? Is this a good practice?

Comment: Instead of a `UNIQUE` constraint, you should create a composite primary key which includes both columns.

Comment: Yes, sorry, *that* is the usual practice.

Answer (score 0):

yes these type of tables having only 2 foreign keys mostly use for login purpose.
its just a connection/relation nothing else.
it helps to extract data easily nothing else

Answer (score 0):

In relational databases its impossible to implement a many-to-many relationship. In this case `Chat` and `User` have a many to many relationship. We need to break a many-to-many relationship into one-to-many relationships by introducing a '[associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)' which contains 2 columns as foreign keys to each of the tables. In this case the `user_chat` is acting as a associative entity.